# JS encodeURIComponent result different from the one created by FORM

Tags: javascript, urlencode, url-encoding, encodeuricomponent

I thought values entered in forms are properly encoded by browsers.

But this simple test file "test_get_vs_encodeuri.html" shows it's not true:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
   <title></title>
</head><body>

<form id="test" action="test_get_vs_encodeuri.html" method="GET" onsubmit="alert(encodeURIComponent(this.one.value));">
   <input name="one" type="text" value="Euro-€">
   <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>

</body></html>
```

When hitting submit button:

**encodeURICompenent encodes input value into "Euro-%E2%82%AC"**

**while browser into the GET query writes only a simple "Euro-%80"**

1. Could someone explain?
2. **How do i encode everything in the same way of the borwser's FORM (windows-1252) using Javascript???** (escape function does not work, encodeURIComponent does not work either)?

Or is encodeURIComponent doing unnecessary conversions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a character encoding issue. Your document is using the charset [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) where the `€` is at position 128 that is encoded with Windows-1252 as 0x80. But [`encodeURICompenent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) is expecting the input to be UTF-8, thus using Unicode’s charset where the `€` is at position 8364 ([PDF](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U20A0.pdf)) that is encoded with UTF-8 0xE282AC.

A solution would be to use UTF-8 for your document as well. Or you write a mapping to convert UTF-8 encoded strings to Windows-1252.

Comment: @Gumbo: thanks I understand now. But this makes me think at another question that I already asked, what this damn encodeURIComponent is useful for? I mean the value encoded by the FORM can not be wrong even if I use cp1252, so why then should I use this damn encodeURIComponent to encode URI, can't I just use a simple JS escape fucntion that returns values identical to the ones encoded by the FORM. I know it might not be nice, but at the end I prefer to encode things exactly like a browser's FORM would do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238515/encodeuricomponent-is-really-useful

Comment: @Marco Demaio: `escape` has a different format: `escape("€")==="%u20AC"`. And as for the purpose of `encodeURIComponent`: Imagine you want to build a URI that contains a `&` as value (like `bar&baz`). `"…?foo=bar&baz"` would yield in two arguments (*foo* and *baz*) because `&` is a special character. But `"…?foo="+encodeURIComponent("bar&baz")` will do it.

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain properly, and I talked rubbish, I know I have to encode characters '&' in GET component, but how do i encode everything in the same way of the FORM with cp1252 using JS? Using escape is not the way, but using encodeURICompoenent is not the way either because € is encoded differently. Is there any function in JS to do that? Sorry, I also updated the question.

Comment: @Marco Demaio: As `encodeURICompoenent` expects the string to be UTF-8 encoded, you will need to write your own encoding function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root of the problem is character encodings.  If I mess around with charset in the meta tag and save the file with different encodings I can get the page to render in the browser like this:

[image: Content encoding issue]
<sub>(source: [boogdesign.com](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/encode/content-encoding-issue.png))</sub>

That `â‚¬` looks a lot like what you're getting from encodeURIComponent.  However I could find no combination of encodings which made any difference to what encodeURIComponent was returning.  I can make a difference to what the GET query returns.  [This is your original page](https://www.boogdesign.com/examples/encode/test-get-vs-encodeuri.html), submitting gives an URL like:

```
test-get-vs-encodeuri.html?one=Euro-%80
```

[This is a UTF-8 version of the page](https://www.boogdesign.com/examples/encode/test-get-vs-encodeuri-utf8.html), submitting gives an URL that looks like this (in Firefox):

```
http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/encode/test-get-vs-encodeuri-utf8.html?one=Euro-€
```

But if I copy and paste it I get:

```
http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/encode/test-get-vs-encodeuri-utf8.html?one=Euro-%E2%82%AC
```

So it looks like if the page is UTF-8 then the GET and encodeURIComponent match.

Comment: encodeURIComponent always assumes UTF-8.  From http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf : 15.1.3.4 encodeURIComponent (uriComponent)
The encodeURIComponent function computes a new version of a URI in which each instance of certain characters is replaced by one, two or three escape sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character.