# Decoding special characters on different file systems with Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to figure this out since hours but I simply can't get my head around what is wrong here.

I have a file named `test_!§$%&_ÄäÜüÖö.mp4` which I want to upload to an AWS S3 bucket. The upload works fine if there are no special characters (yes I've tried the official answer from the AWS docs by using `decodeURIComponnet(filename)`, but this did not work). I'm not so fuzzed about the special characters `!§$%&` but I do want the German Umlaute to be converted. Thus I'm doing three things:

```js
// remove all special chars (key comes from the file to upload)
let cleanKey = key.replace(/[°^!"§$%&\\()[\]{}=?*+#<>]/g, "");

// convert spaces to `_`
cleanKey = cleanKey.replace(" ", "_");

// convert German characters
const characters = [...cleanKey].map(char => {

  switch (encodeURI(char)) {
    case encodeURI("Ä"):
      return "Ae";
    case encodeURI("ä"):
      return "ae";
    case encodeURI("Ö"):
      return "Oe";
    case encodeURI("ö"):
      return "oe";
    case encodeURI("Ü"):
      return "Ue";
    case encodeURI("ü"):
      return "ue";
    default:
      return char;
  }
});

// return converted key
return characters.join("");
```

The problem is that the characters from my file system (MacOS 12.0.1) do not match in the `switch` statement. I have read a couple of discussions (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253895/special-character-not-displaying-as-expected) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607946/js-encodeuricomponent-result-different-from-the-one-created-by-form)) and it seems that character decoding works different on each operating system. Unfortunately I could not figure out **how I would convert** my filename into a **regular UTF-8 string** (if this even exists) to parse out the non valid characters?

I know that my approach is probably not really production ready (eg if someone wants to upload a file written in Hebrew letters), so if someone has a better solution for not getting the

> `The specified key does not exist`

error, please let me know.